# Rearrange layout on hover using Angular masonry

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html, jquery-masonry

I am using passy's angular-masonry for arranging data. whenever page load data shows in this way

[image: design on masonry]

These div with different data have effects on hover. whenever mouseenter hidden div get shown and disappeared on mouseleave. On mouseover on a div i reload masonry layout , which results in floating div's. On reload div start floating and reload layout.

I need things to be shown in this manner

[image]

So how can we get this without getting all floating div's rearranging themseleves. Only current div  expand and collapse(i.e showing hidden divs). Any suggestion would be appreciated